# Как проверить вхождение точки координат в полигон на Python?

Tags: python, pandas, geo

Есть несколько датасетов со столбцами id, latitude, longitude, нужно получить к каждой строке административный регион по координатам.
Точек суммарно на 22 ГБ, соответственно решения с API геокодеров не подошли: либо медленно, либо платно.

Откопал в интернете мультиполигоны всех административных регионов России в CSV формате. Строка выглядит примерно вот так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите какие инструменты/библиотеки могут помочь решить задачу в адекватные сроки? Может есть какие-то +/- готовые решения для того чтобы быстро находить в какой из полигонов входит точка?

P.S. Адекватные сроки это хотя бы исчисляемые днями работы ПК, а не неделями

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться модулями:

- [GeoPandas](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/getting_started/introduction.html) + [shapely](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html)
- [cuDF](https://github.com/rapidsai/cudf) + [cuSpatial](https://github.com/rapidsai/cuspatial)

В англоязычной версии SO есть [похожий вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36399381/5741205) и в ответах на него показаны варианты решения и сравнение производительности.